# How to display javascript label inside <td> table column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding display of data in a table .
The example code posted here is a part of my code within a table. I think this is sufficient for the question:

If I put the

```
<label id="HMI_scaled">0</label>
```

outside the table on a random place in my page, the data is displayed.

HMI_scaled is a value automatically updated thanks to the javascript shown later in this text. The problem is that I don't know how to type the syntax for displaying it in my table. I tried, but it does not update as it does outside the table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="static_field">Level [m]:</td>
    <td class="output_field"><label id="HMI_scaled">0</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT FOR HMI_scaled:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("IOwebserver.htm", function(result){
            $('#HMI_scaled').text(result.trim());
        });
    },1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
td.output_field
{
    font-size : 12px;
    background-color : rgb(221,221,221);
    text-align : left;
    width : 150px;
    height : 21px;
}

td.static_field
{
    font-size : 12px;
    text-align : right;
    width : 150px;
    height : 21px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  IOwebserver.htm
    :="webdata".HMI_scaled:
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no problems with your code, and it works for me. See below where I replaced your ajax-call with code to show current time every second. It works, no matter where the `<label>` is.

Check that you made no HTML typos, and that you included jQuery on top of the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
        var result = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        $('#HMI_scaled').text(result.trim());
        $('#HMI_scaled_2').text(result.trim());
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="static_field">Level [m]:</td>
    <td class="output_field">Inside table -&gt; <label id="HMI_scaled">0</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Outside table -&gt; <label id="HMI_scaled_2">0</label>
```

Comment: Aha, well just remember then that element-ids *must be unique* in every page. Avoid duplicate ids on the page, it is not valid HTML, and jQuery will always return only the first item if you search using `$('#someId')`.

Comment: Ok, great. I do not know if you saw my other post here, but do you have any experience with using multiple tags with JSON structure?

Comment: That is a different / new question I believe.

Comment: Good point. I posted here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222950/show-several-tags-with-json-structure-in-siemens-s7-webserver