# Show several tags with JSON structure in Siemens s7 webserver

Tags: javascript, html, json, siemens, s7-1200

I am using a Siemens S7-1200 PLC with integrated webserver.
I want to show multiple analog values from the PLC in the webpage using javascript.  With one tag it works great, but how do I add and present multiple tags using JSON structure?

I have done the following: 
 - Updated the javascript with a suggested code
 - Updated the htm file that the script reads from

But I do not know if i have done this correct and how do I then call
   for the different variables.

**THIS IS THE TABLE I WANT TO DISPKLAY THE DATA IN:**

```
    <table>

<tr>
    <td class="static_field">Nivå [m]:</td>
    <td class="output_field"><label id="HMI_skalert">0</label></td>     
</tr>

<tr>                    
    <td class="static_field">Masse [tonn]:</td>
    <td class="output_field"><label id="Tank1_masse">0</label></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

---

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON("IOwebserver.htm", function(result){

               HMI_skalert= result.HMI_skalert  
                Tank1_masse=result.Tank1_masse

            });
        },1000);
        });
    </script>
```

---

**FILE:**
IOwebserver.htm

```
{
":="webdata".HMI_skalert:",
":="webdata".Tank1_masse:"
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look on this article... *https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/*

You haven´t a return key in JSON in  IOwebserver.htm file.

"**:="webdata".HMI_skalert:**" -> value of JSON object which use **AWP command** in this case.. 
:="Name_of_DataBlock".variable: -> Symbols (:=) and (:) are boundaries of AWP command used in Simatic WebServer

So try to remake this file like this:

```
{
 "HMI_skalert":":='webdata'.HMI_skalert:",
 "Tank1_masse":":='webdata'.Tank1_masse:"
}
```

If this will not work try to swap apostrophes dobule quotes (") by one (').

For example I use a interval loading XML file to load 57 variables for Simatic S7-S1200 WebServer. For more information contact me..